# Can ICC donate any type funds to infected or injured players?

Tags: cricket

I am actually new to cricket game . I have seen many times that players got badly injured due to ball being hit . Mostly players belongs to middle  and lower class families . Just like army Is there any committee who take action about these type of circumstances that happened?

Comment: People playing sport at a local level are 1. nothing to do with the ICC except insofar as they happen to play cricket, and 2. doing it at their own risk like every other amateur sports player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ICC is not responsible for any tragedy related to players  and ICC will not give  funds to injured players but their boards will rescue them in terms of funding.

Answer (score 1):

If the injury happens in a game being played in a competition organised by a specific cricket board or organisation, that organisation MAY have insurance for this sort of eventuality, or they may not. You'd need to enquire with the organisation in question to get a specific answer.